# material ui <ExpansionPanel> onChange pass variable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a panel looks as following:

```
  render () {
    const testID = this.props.testID
    console.log(testID) // has value here
    return (
      <ExpansionPanel onChange={(testID) => console.log(testID)}>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <Typography>SOME TITLE</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails}>
          SOME DETAILS
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    )
  }
```

I want to get this `testID` when user click to expend the panel.

The reason is later I can use this `testID` to fetch data from server and display the data under `< ExpansionPanelDetails >`.

But what it printed at the moment is something as following:

`Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, …}`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `onChange={() => console.log(this.props.testID)}` ?

Comment: Ah yes... I passed the variable as argument...Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing here is naming the React Synthetic event argument as `testId`. It doesn't have the value of your variable because the argument having the same name is overwriting it in that arrow function.

If you still want to use an arrow function, you could rename or not use the first argument (event), and use the testId variable from the outer scope.

```
() => { console.log(this.props.testId); }
```

Or, you could add a function to your class:

```
handleExpansionPanelChange = (ev) => {
    const testID = this.props.testID;
    console.log(testID);
}
```

And then in your render function, pass `this.handleExpansionPanelChange` to the ExpansionPanel's onChange prop.

Or you could bind the method you would pass to the ExpansionPanel's onChange prop to have the testId value pre-set:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call